# Angular8: Cannot find name Omit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, angular8

I added '[ngx-highlightjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-highlightjs)' to my Angular8 project and my TypeScript can not find [Omit](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/the-omit-helper-type-in-typescript) class. I got this error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/highlight.js/types/index.d.ts(78,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Omit'.
node_modules/highlight.js/types/index.d.ts(175,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Omit'.
node_modules/ngx-highlightjs/lib/highlight.service.d.ts(7,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
```

My TypeScript version is 4.1.0 and I also try with 3.4.5

Do you have any solutions for this error? My code does not even compile...

Comment: Which version of ngx-highlightjs do you use

Comment: The last: "ngx-highlightjs": "^4.1.2"